# Route not working in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

ok I am trying to invoke a DELETE HTTP command using embedded ruby.

SO my code is:

```
<li><%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
```

in my routes I got

```
  #Note the use of via: :delete for the signout route, which indicated that it should be invoked using an HTTP DELETE request
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

but I get this error!

```
No route matches [GET] "/signout"
```

I wrote "method: "delete" !! so why does it give me a GET error? ?

guys applying what you told me, including application.js breaks my js code!!
Here is my head code:

```
    </head>

        <!-- Ruby Code -->
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "scaffold" %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "myCSS/home.css", :media => "all" %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "myCSS/JS_dropdown_menu.css", :media => "all" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "myJS/jquery-1.7.js" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "myJS/hoverIntent.js" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "myJS/jquery.dropdown.js" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "application.js" %>

        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    </head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to make a GET request to a route that would only respond to DELETE.

Why isn't this working? You probably haven't included `application.js` using this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
```

This would include the `jquery.js` and `jquery_ujs.js` files that would provide the `method: "delete"` functionality for your link.

Comment: The `method: 'delete'` is supposed to send a DELETE request.

Comment: Including the jquery-1.7 version is probably conflicting with the one typically included by application.js. Please show the code inside application.js.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality of passing `method: 'delete'` relies on having a functioning UJS library. The first thing I would do is make sure that `jquery` and `jquery_ujs` JavaScript files are being included correctly.

Comment: you need jquery_ujs, not application.js